# What's wrong with my normal maps?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, baking, normal-map

I'm attempting to bake a normal map from a sculpt. Some of the UV islands intentionally overlap for the purpose of mirroring certain details and conserving space.

However, the normal map doesn't look quite right:

[image: The character model, with the baked normal map.]

[image: Back view of the character model with the normal map.]

If I look closely enough, I can even find various body parts in places they shouldn't be.

[image: A compilation of the stuff seen in the normal map.]

I feel like I've exhausted everything I could've done to get this to look right. So far, I've:

- Adjusted the extrusion
- Adjusted the max ray distance
- Enabled "Cage" under "Selected to Active"
- Lowered the margin under "Output"
- Separated the overlapping tiles
- Set the rendering device to "GPU Compute" (which wasn't enabled in preferences, oops)
- Upgraded from Blender 2.91 to 2.93 without importing settings
- Applied a subdivision surface and a shrinkwrap modifier to my low-res model in order to make it align even more with the high-res model

Each of these steps have either slightly altered the results or made no difference at all. I've even created a test project in an attempt to replicate the issue, only to end up with a clean normal map.

[image: The test project, with a successfully baked normal map.]

Baking normal maps for character models has always been a huge struggle I've wanted to overcome. [I've been trying to figure this out for a while,](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/202658/why-does-my-normal-map-appear-to-have-holes-in-it) and while there's been some improvement, I still can't get it quite right. I just feel like I've been missing something really obvious.

I can DM the project files by request. Thanks you so much in advance!

Comment: I dont see you mentioning recalculating your normals, did you try it? Alt+N and recalculate, this may be due to normals issue or shading(if not I hope someone will find answer

Comment: hello maybe share your file if you want us to try?

Comment: @MikoCG I've recalculated my normals and averaged my face area! Unfortunately, that didn't change the output.

Comment: @moonboots I can't seem to find a way to DM you, so [here's](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T3pSt1S5g2ZN7DhxFQi0LNMYx1OagDsa/view?usp=sharing) the link to the project!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you said you have done this, I still believe adjusting extrusion to something like ~0.02m would fix the issue (there is a clear projection of one leg on the other), and also check face orientations.

Comment: Setting the extrusion to 0.02m helped a ton! [Here's](https://i.imgur.com/QiZP7E4.jpg) what the front view looks like now, and [here's](https://i.imgur.com/78k2SXJ.jpg) the rear view. I have backface culling enabled in viewport shading, but I recalculated the normals and averaged the face area just in case. (It didn't change the output though.)

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer, but I just want to mention that I also [touched up the normal map](https://i.imgur.com/AmTR6X3.jpg) in texture paint mode! It seems to be virtually impossible to bake a perfect normal map in any program, but an extrusion of 0.02 m is optimal. Thank you!